# Attempting to change datatype and getting errors in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, complex-data-types

I have a dataset that looks like this

[image]

and the datatypes looks like this

[image]

I am attempting the change the datatype of cubicinches and weightlbs into float or integer but none of the options is working:

```
df["cubicinches"]=df["cubicinches"].astype(float)

df = df.astype({"weightlbs": float, "cubicinches": float})

df['weightlbs'] = pd.to_numeric(df['weightlbs'])
```

Comment: Try: `df["cubicinches"]=pd.to_numeric(df["cubicinches"], errors='coerce')`

Comment: @enke. I think it's not a problem to convert the column to float but a problem of naming column. Check the leading whitespace.

Comment: @Corralien that's very good catch :-)

Answer (score 0):

There could be an entry in one of the mentioned columns that is an actual string with letters or so. To check, you can get the unique values for each column to try to find it.

e.g.

```
df["cubicinches"].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: it seems most of your columns have a leading whitespace before their name: `'cubicinches'` is `' cubicinches'`. What is exactly the error message?

Try before:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

If you can't cast to `float` it's because you have some non numeric values in your column. As suggested by @enke, use `pd.to_numeric` in a different way.

You can find wrong values with:

```
out = df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['cubicinches'], errors='coerce').isna(), 'cubicinches']
print(out)

# Output
2    wrong
3    value
Name: cubicinches, dtype: object
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cubicinches': ['3.2', '0.8', 'wrong', 'value', '7.78']})
print(df)

# Output
  cubicinches
0         3.2
1         0.8
2       wrong
3       value
4        7.78
```